# How to make a grid item not stretch the whole row if there is only 1 item in it with auto-fit

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

I made a responsive grid layout with repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">Card</div>
        <div class="card">Card</div>
        <div class="card">Card</div>
        <div class="card">Card</div>
        <div class="card">Card</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    gap: 50px;
}

.card {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

On a laptop each row has 3 cards:
[3 cards in a row on laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgwou.png)

On a tablet each row has 2 cards:
[2 cards in a row on tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7uTI.png)

If the grid only has 1 card then the card stretches the whole row:
[1 grid item in row that stretches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUwJ2.png)

I want the card not to stretch completely but leave space for the second and third card like in this drawing:
[desirable effect for laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QirKa.png)

And when there can be 2 cards in 1 row at max, it should look like this:
[desirable effect for tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3puAA.png)

I tried to add invisible cards:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">Card</div>
        <div class="card invis"></div>
        <div class="card invis"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    gap: 50px;
}

.card {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}

.invis {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Desirable effect created with invisible cards:
[imperfect solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIzt4.png)

That worked but there was a problem when the screen was completely filled with cards. All the normal cards fit on the screen. But the invisible cards that come after the normal cards cause the container to overflow and a scrollbar appears so you can scroll down and 'see' the invisible cards which is not desirable.
Image of scrollbar appearing because of the invisible cards at the bottom of the container element. Scrollbar wouldn't appear if there were no invisible elements:
[scrollbar appearing because of invisible cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5MIQ.png)

I could try to make the invisible cards go away when I don't need them anymore with JavaScript, but I don't know if using invisible cards is a good idea. I wonder if there is a proper way of setting the size of a single grid item to the size it would have when the row was filled with more items using repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr)

Comment: don't use `auto-fit` but `auto-fill`

Answer (score 1):

Use `auto-fill` instead of `auto-fit`. The difference is, that the grid will not span the entire width if the total width of all items is smaller then the container width:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 50px;
}

.card {
  min-height: 30vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```